# How to print/log outputs within foreachBatch function?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

Using table streaming, I am trying to write stream using foreachBatch

```
df.writestream
.format("delta")
.foreachBatch(WriteStreamToDelta)
...
```

WriteStreamToDelta looks like

```
def WriteStreamToDelta(microDF, batch_id):
   microDFWrangled = microDF."some_transformations"
   
   print(microDFWrangled.count()) <-- How do I achieve the equivalence of this?

   microDFWrangled.writeStream...
```

I would like to view the number of rows in

1. Notebook, below the writeStream cell
2. Driver Log
3. Create a list to append number of rows for each micro batch.

Answer (score 1):

Running `microDFWrangled.count()` in each microbatch is going to be a bit expensive thing. I believe much more efficient is to involve `StreamingQueryListener` which can send output to the console, to the driver logs, to external database etc.

StreamingQueryListener is efficient because it uses internal streaming statistics, so no need to run extra computation just to get the record count.

However, in case of PySpark, this feature works in Databricks starting 11.0.
And in OSS spark I think it is available only since the latest releases

Reference: https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/05/27/how-to-monitor-streaming-queries-in-pyspark.html

---

If you still want to send the output using print(), consider to add `.awaitTermination()` as the last chained statement:

```py
df.writestream
.format("delta")
.foreachBatch(WriteStreamToDelta)
.Start()
.awaitTermination()
```